# should I use Omniture event serialization for multi-category tracking under same user session

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

I would like to use a single Omniture event for category visits. When a user visit a page http://domain.com/categoryA/index.jsp. So I do

```
s.evar1 = categoryA ( this gets populated dynamically via JS script)
s.events = event1,event2
```

I have setup my

```
event1 to record once per visit (let Omniture do dedup) 
event2 to always record (want to know category popularity)
```

Now when the a the same above user visits to categoryB page under http://domain.com/categoryB/index.jsp the above code gets fired with categoryB as evar1. What happens to event1? Does it get recorded or it doesn't cos Omniture already received value for the session and it will just ignore it?

Is it where I should serialisation? I can pass an id e.g event1:1234 but the problem is my ID gets generated every time a user reloads the page or go back and forth from that page. How can I track 2 category `visit` event under same session using single event?

Thank you

Comment: If you look at an eVar1 report with the metrics "visits" and "page views", won't that give you the data you're looking for? I don't think you need those events.

Comment: Yes, thats correct. But I am in an Ajax env. In any case I need to fire a custom event. - Is there a possibility? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you've specifically set event1 to record once per visit using report suite settings, any subsequent hits to event1 in that same visit are ignored.

If you'd like to serialize event1 to only record once per visit per category, you could use event ID serialization, pull the visitor ID data from the cookie and append it with the category they are browsing. For example, when they visit category A, you'd set:

`s.events="event1:[visitorID]+[categoryA]";`

And when they visit category B:

`s.events="event1:[same visitorID]+[categoryB]";`

If they visit the same category multiple times, event1 is only recorded once. If they visit 5 different categories, event1 is triggered 5 times (once for each category visited).

Comment: I don't think I've seen this `event` syntax before, and I can't seem to find it in the online documentation.  Do you have documentation for this? e.g, I am unclear on how that would even work. How would AA know that `[categoryA]` in that context belongs to the eVar?  Also, maybe I misunderstand, but the visitor ID value from the cookie does not conform to the limitations of [event serialization](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/implement/event_serialization_impl.html), and it may not even be exposed, depending on what type of implementation is used (default 3rd party cookie imp).

Comment: My ballpark guess here is maybe you meant to show eVar serialization, e.g. `s.eVar="[categoryA]:[serialize id]";` but please can you link documentation for that `event` syntax if there is any, so that I may learn it~

Comment: both eVars and events can be serialized - here's more information on event serialization: http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/implement/event_serialization_impl.html. You are correct that it may/may not be exposed depending on the implementation, however it could work fairly easily if first party cookies are used or if they have a way to pull any sort of unique identifier.

Comment: Hello, I have tried (somewhat) the above method. My first difficulty was to get the VisitorID and I was unable to get it. However while looking for it I found something call "s.fid" (fall back ID) and the value is identical to "Digital Pulse" Debugger's "Visitor ID". With this "s.fid" I run two events one "record once per visit" and the second as per @Gigazelle suggestion. Unfortunately the event count was lower in serialised then "record once per visit". I am using 3rd party cookie - so probably the above will not work for me. Anyway I can get "visitorID" using my implementation.

Comment: Furthermore I am guessing the reason "s_fid serialisation" was lower cos the s_fid cookie lifetime (2 years), so all subsequent visit to that category from the same user "after the first visit" was ignored, where as "record once per visit" is based on "visits" and not "visitor".

Comment: @Gigazelle well yes I know you can serialize eVars.. but my question was for you to link to documention for that particular `event` syntax where you have `"event1:[visitorID]+[categoryA]"`. because I've never seen that before. I know you can serialize events but I've never seen that `+[categoryA]` syntax that you added

Comment: @wailer as I mentioned, the visitorID is not exposed with the default 3rd party cookie imp. This is a browser security restriction - javascript can only read cookies for the domain the page is hosted on.  But it doesn't matter anyway because it's too long and has invalid chars for the expected serial id format.

Comment: But, the overall goal is to create a unique id that is used for the duration of the visit, and that's easy enough to do via other means, e.g. just creating a timestamp and storing that in a session cookie. I would not recommend using `s_fid` because it is too long. Read the link I posted for serialization for the format expectations

Comment: Ah, my apologies - the code examples I meant in the example were string concatenations, and I realized that even if it were to work, it would be visitor-based and not visit-based. Perhaps the best way to do it would be via keeping categories visited in a session cookie and only populate the eVar if the current category is not listed in the cookie.

Comment: i would also advise against using s_fid, as that's the fallback cookie identification method.

Comment: @Crayon Violent - Just wondering is there a easy way to write/read such time based session cookie using DTM? I am guessing not? that means it needs to be in the server side by IT which I have no access to.

Comment: @wailer okay so basically you just need a unique id to persist for the duration of a visit.  Generating the current timestamp is the simplest thing, and is a valid format for a serial id, though there is a possibility of collision with other visitors, so you may want to do something a little more unique, like concat an additional randomly generated alphanumeric string to it.

Comment: @wailer for persisting it: yes, in DTM you can create a data element of **Custom Script** type and put your code that generates and returns the unique value based on timestamp and random string.  Then for **Remember this value** option, set it to "Session".  Alternatively, if you want to write your own code elsewhere, you can use `_satellite.getCookie()` and `_satellite.readCookie()` methods for cookie reading/writing, or just use Omniture's `s.c_w()` and `s.c_r()` methods

Comment: @Gigazelle also made a good suggestion for an alternative to serializing it: store the category in a cookie and only pop the eVar if not found.  I like this alternative because it eliminates the possibility of serial id collision. My only hangup about it is depending on how long your category names are, how many there are, how many a visitor is likely to view `n` amount, etc.. that cookie could get quite long and there is an upper limit to how long a cookie can be that you need to consider, especially if you happen to be making use of Omniture's combined cookie plugin